# Looking for horizontal image slider for my site

Tags: javascript, blogger, widgets

Any javascript tool which will take url of my images and links. It should work like a horizontalimage slider. If some one clicks on the image, it should redirect to the respective link.

Has anybody seen any java script widget for the Horizontal image slider.

Comment: stackoverflow.com please sir

Comment: We really need to define the boundaries, so ppl will understand which question belongs to stackoverflow and which belongs to webmasters... :-(

Comment: Any reason for down voting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Nivo Slider on Blogger](http://www.abu-farhan.com/2011/07/automatic-content-slider-for-blogger-using-nivo-slider-part-1/).com blogs. It works just like the way you described in your post. In case of wordpress, Nivo slider and [Wp Cycle](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-cycle) are two plugins that can be used to get the desired result.